# "UNAUTHENTICATED: Access Denied - missing meta site id"

Tags: velo

when uploading image to the wix store with the wix access token, I met the following error
{
"message": "UNAUTHENTICATED: Access Denied - missing meta site id",
"errorCode": -100,
"details": {}
}

the body parameter is the following:
{
"url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3993471/pexels-photo-3993471.jpeg",
"mediaType": "IMAGE",
"displayName": "hair_img",
"parentFolderId": "media-root",
"private": false
}
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFxfJ.png)

how to fix this issue?